# AngularJS official docs conventions

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angularJS and going through the official documentation.

Every API element has this sublist (highlighted in the red rectangle in the image).

I searched a lot but I am still not clear what it represents. Can anyone help please?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sublists are used for analogous behaviours between the subject and the sublist item. For example if you are reading about $route, then $routeProvider will also enlighten your concept about routing.

Comment: Try not using abbreviations and using proper grammar while posting on SO. The community is a bit strict regarding that. ;)

Comment: Thanks i will take care of it:-)